Spring Security @CrossOrigin No Access-Control-Allow-Origin
I am attempting to use @CrossOrigin to annotate my Spring MVC @RestController classes in a Spring Boot 3.3 application. This application uses a JWT for authentication, and requires the "Authorization" header to be allowed for requests. I would also like to allow other custom headers in the future.
Unfortunately, my requests fail in the browser (Chrome) with this message:
POST http://localhost:8080/application/api/properties/getAllProp net::ERR_FAILED

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/application/api/properties/getAllProp' 
from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to 
preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource.

I'm stumped as to what I've done wrong. Here's the API endpoint method, with @CrossOrigin annotation:
    @CrossOrigin(origins={"http://localhost:4200","http://localhost:8080"}, allowCredentials = "true")
    @PostMapping("/api/**")
    public ResponseEntity<?> apiGateway(
            @RequestBody ApiRequest input,
            @AuthenticationPrincipal String userId,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {


    }

Here is my Spring Security Filter SecurityFilterChain:
        // @formatter:off
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> {
                    authorize.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })

            .sessionManagement((session) -> {
                session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
            })
            .exceptionHandling((handler) -> {
                handler.authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized"));
            })
            
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
            .logout((logout) -> logout.disable())
            .build();
        // @formatter:on

I am NOT configuring CORS Mappings a WebMvcConfigurer.
I've searched previous questions and multiple sites looking for help before posting this.

You didn't enable CORS in your filter chain.
